# Custom log4net appender it is not working unless I am actively debugging the application

Tags: asp.net, log4net, log4net-appender

I’ve created a custom log4net appender, it works great when I am debugging the application, but as soon as I deploy the application (even in debug mode) it stops working.

If I do a remote debug on the server (by attaching to process) my custom appender works just fine.

I've added this to the Assemblyinfo.cs.
`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`

And in the Application_Start inside the Global.asax file I have:
`log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();`

One thing that I notice, is that the deployed application does call the method ActivateOptions(), but it is either not calling Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) or it is just not working.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you got your logging configuration in the app.config/web.config, or in a separate file?

Comment: I have the configuration in the web.config

Comment: OK. You don't need to use both those XmlConfigurator options, either one will do. In fact, I'm suspect "Watch = true" is redundant unless you are using an external file for config (which you are not).
Can you try eliminating a file write permission issue by putting a fully qualified absolute path for the log file in the config, and ensuring that location has everyone with full control? (This is a test - I don't suggest you leave the permissions like that!)

Comment: My custom log writes to Azure Table storage, so it is not an issue with the file permissions.  I got it to work for now by adding the custom appender class directly into the web project, instead of having it on an external class library.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!